Exploring Convergence and Properties of Novel Zeta-Like Functions for Complex $s$
I am studying a family of functions involving infinite series, infinite products, and exponential towers, and would appreciate insights into their convergence and properties, particularly for complex (s). Below are the three functions under investigation:

The classical exponential tower:
$\mathop{E}_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n = a_0^{a_1^{a_2^{\cdots}}}$
This forms the base for my definitions. Assuming all $a_n > 0$, it is known to converge under certain conditions (e.g., $e^{-e} \leq a_n \leq e^{\frac{1}{e}}$).

The Classical Riemann zeta function:
$\zeta_{\alpha}(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$

A novel function inspired by the Riemann zeta function:
$\zeta_{\beta}(s) = \frac{1}{2} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n^s}\right)$

Another novel zeta-like function:
$\zeta_{\gamma}(s) = \frac{1}{\left( e^{\frac{1}{e}}+\frac{1}{2e}\right)^e} \mathop{E}_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(e^{\frac{1}{e}} + \frac{1}{2en^{s+1}}\right)$


Key observations and questions:

All three functions converge for $\mathrm{Re}(s) > 1$ and approach $1$ as $s \to \infty$.
I am particularly interested in understanding:

Convergence conditions for $\zeta_{\gamma}(s)$, particularly for complex $s$.
Analytic properties, such as whether $\zeta_{\beta}(s)$ and $\zeta_{\gamma}(s)$ can be analytically continued to $\mathrm{Re}(s) \leq 1$.
Growth behavior of $\zeta_{\gamma}(s)$ as $\mathrm{Im}(s) \to \infty$.



Have these functions, particularly $\zeta_{\beta}$ and $\zeta_{\gamma}$, been studied before in any context? If not, I would appreciate guidance on methods or references to analyze such functions.
Any insights into their behavior for complex $s$ would be valuable!

Is this related to this zeta like power tower question?
